# How To Do SUM With case

Tags: sql

when I use the following query, the results appear as I wanted:

```
select (TARIF + TAMBAHAN - (case when (select NILAI from PROMOTRIP where KODETRIP = OD.KODETRIP and URUTAN = OD.URUTAN) is null then 0 else (select NILAI from PROMOTRIP where KODETRIP = OD.KODETRIP and URUTAN = OD.URUTAN) end)) from ORDERDETAIL OD where KODETRIP = 'TR201408060051' and TGLBATAL is null
```

[image]

But when I want to add it, the result errors:

[image]

Comment: Please add your queries and results in textual form.

Comment: select 
(TARIF + TAMBAHAN - 
(case when 
(select NILAI from PROMOTRIP where KODETRIP  = OD.KODETRIP and URUTAN = OD.URUTAN) is null then 0 
else 
(select NILAI from PROMOTRIP where KODETRIP  = OD.KODETRIP and URUTAN = OD.URUTAN) end))
from ORDERDETAIL OD where KODETRIP = 'TR201408060051' and TGLBATAL is null

Result : 
01. 90000,00
02. 70000,00
03. 70000,00
04. 95000,00
05. 85000,00
06. 85000,00
07. 65000,00
08. 65000,00
09. 70000,00
10. 65000,00
11. 150000,00

Comment: I really didn't like the way you have used lower case for SQL keywords and upper case for table/column names. It is generally the other way around.

Comment: And I use lower case all the way. Upper case keywords feels so 70's Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

Try incorporating your first query as a nested query and use `SUM` on the outer query. Something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(*) FROM (YOUR_FIRST_QUERY)
```

Comment: Consider clicking the green tick in case this answer solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This will do.

```
SELECT SUM(RES) FROM (
select (TARIF + TAMBAHAN - (case when (select NILAI from PROMOTRIP where 
KODETRIP = OD.KODETRIP and URUTAN = OD.URUTAN) is null then 0 else (select 
NILAI from PROMOTRIP where KODETRIP = OD.KODETRIP and URUTAN = OD.URUTAN) 
end)) AS RES from ORDERDETAIL OD where KODETRIP = 'TR201408060051' and 
TGLBATAL is null )A
```